# generating plural forms into a .pot file

Tags: python, internationalization, xgettext

I'm internationalizing a python program and cant get plural forms into the .pot file.  I have marked string that require plural translations with a _pl() eg.

`self.write_info(_pl("%(num)d track checked", "%(num)d tracks checked",
                     song_obj.song_count) % {"num" : song_obj.song_count})`

Then I'm running:
`xgettext --language=Python --keyword=_pl --output=output.pot *.py`
Only the first (singular) string is generated in the pot file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used this with Python, and can't test at the moment, but try `--keyword=_pl:1,2` instead.

From the GNU gettext [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#xgettext-Invocation):

> --keyword[=keywordspec]’
>       Additional keyword to be looked for (without keywordspec means not to use default keywords).
>
> If keywordspec is a C identifier id, xgettext looks for strings in the first argument of each call to the function or macro id. If keywordspec is of the form ‘id:argnum’, xgettext looks for strings in the argnumth argument of the call. If keywordspec is of the form ‘id:argnum1,argnum2’, xgettext looks for strings in the argnum1st argument and in the argnum2nd argument of the call, and treats them as singular/plural variants for a message with plural handling.